# Web API Security ( Authentication )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

### Background:

I've implemented a Web-API (.NET), now I need to do the most important thing,
Secure it.

As I investigate this topic I understand that the common way is the **Bearer Token.**

Now we getting to my problem.

### My Problem

**On one side:**

Every article I saw (that explains the concept and the way to implement it over .NET) starts from a project with a Web API template that holds MVC and Web API and in the authentication field choose one option from Individual / Organizational / Windows .

**On the other side:**

I don't need a MVC project, I need only Web API (without any GUI) that the reason I choose the empty project and check the Web API checkbox, in that way I cant choose an authentication type, I forced to start with no authentication.

### Questions:

1.Do I bound to use MVC to get authentication ? if not how can I do it from pure Web API project ?

2.Maybe I will create an Authentication Server (that only generates tokens) from that Web API template (with the possibility of choosing authentication type) ? (and use the token on the real Web API)

3.There is any benefits of implement the Authentication Server on a different project and on different server ? ([Kerberos style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) )

**P.S** I want to use an out of the box solution because the security aspect is the most important one (to my opinion) and should be flawless.

Comment: I think to answer this we need more information on the project as '... implementing a web-API' doesn't make sense. Web API is a framework and MVC is a common pattern used with webapi. For example, if you needed to authenticate a restful service to retrieve how much a person has in their bank. One way it's to authenticate using an attribute on each controller. Hope that helps

Comment: take a look at this article:http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a blog on this topic called 'Securing and securely calling Web API and [Authorize]': http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2015/03/25/securing-and-working-securely-with-web-api.aspx. I think if you read this, you'll have all your answers.

The Web API template does include MVC by default so that you get the automated docs feature (which is a great feature to have). However the authentication part is related to a core ASP.net feature, not specific to MVC or Web API. You'll need to enable one of the authentication options to secure your API using .net's built in security features.

If you do not want the MVC project that comes with Web API, just delete it after the project has been created. It is contained within the 'areas' folder. If you delete that folder, you'll be running on pure web api.

To answer your specific questions:

1) No you do not need an MVC project to secure an API project. You can use the [Authorize] attribute on your API controllers and actions.

2) an authentication server gets created by default with the web api template. You can access it and get tokens via http:///Token

3) No, you need to use the api itself to serve valid tokens for secured controller/action requests

Hope that helps. If not, then please be a bit more specific with your questions.